# How does Mongo handle a tie when sorting?

Tags: mongodb

I have a number of documents where the timestamp happens to be the same, as a result of less than stellar process of creating test data.

When sorting by the timestamp (desc), what other factor does Mongo take into account to sort?

Comment: Don't nail me on that, but iirc, the position in the index (if applicable) or the datafile determines the position in the result set in an otherwise tied sort.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think Mongo internally tries to solve a tie on a sort.

That said, to be on the safe side, you can pass a 2nd sort argument to the `sort()` function, for example, if I have `comments` sorted by `created` date (desc) and further by the text of the comment as `comment`.

```
db.comments.find().sort({created:-1,comment:1})
```